# Drupal Solr not working with numerical search terms

Tags: 7, search

So this is quite a strange one:

I have a site hooked up to a Solr instance through Search API. All seems to work fine, apart from a few edge-case issues surrounding searching for content containing numerical characters.

For example, if I have a piece of content called `'Adam ist 23'` (I changed 'is' for 'ist' to get around stopwords being ignored), here are the search terms and results:

```
Search: Adam ist 23
Result: No results found

Search: Adam ist
Result: Adam ist 23

Search: Adam ist 2
Result: Adam ist 23

Search: Adam ist 3
Result: Adam ist 23

Search: Adam ist 2 3
Result: Adam ist 23
```

It seems to only affect search results where my search terms match the entire numerical value found within the title (or any indexed field, for that matter).

I found a thread on here with a recommendation to make a change to the following line in config.xml, however it did not fix my issue:

I'm at a loss to what's going on here, so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: I'm on Drupal version 7.50